# filtering nested ng-repeat with the outer ng-repeat's object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm trying to do two nested ng-repeats with two json's, where the second ng-repeat is filtered by the parameter of the first ng-repeat.

First json $scope.matches contains the information on every match in the World Cup.
The second json @scope.predictions contains each users predictions for each game.

Now i want to ng-repeat a match as a header, and then list all of the predictions for that specific game. Repeat until every prediction is listed under the right game. I have match.matchnumber = prediction.matchnumber.

In my Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/GQmYxZiO53nkIBVczaS9?p=preview you can see, that the filter doesn't work, since it applies to every object parameter, and not only matchnumber.

What is the easiest way to make this work?
Maybe I should combine the jsons into an filtered array? How would this be done the smart way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to filter by specific property, you need to pass an object with the property-name as key and the search-term as value:

```
ng-repeat="p in predictions | filter:{matchnumber: match.matchnumber}"
```

<sub>The above filter will return only those predictions whose `matchnumber` property matches `match.matchnumber`.</sub>

---

See, also, this **[updated demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8CrXfqhu2Zc7PPXQanT8?p=preview)**.

---

<sub>That said, it is probably not very efficient to loop over **all** predictions for each match in every digest loop. A better aporoach would be to process both JSONs and build a 3rd one that contains all necessary data, such that no filtering is required in the view.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply! That was exactly what I needed!